# How to disable Camunda http and soap connectors

Tags: rest, http, camunda, connector

The docmentation only tells me how to add more connectors, but I cannot find anywhere to tell me how to stop those connectors from being loaded. Removing the camunda-connector libs from the classpath just causes the ProcessEngineConfiguration to throw ClassNotFoundException.

We use Camunda 7.17.0 as an embedded workflow engine that doesn't need to be accessed through REST or SOAP, so I want to close those avenues of attack.